# Why I have error when use API from DummyJSON

Tags: reactjs, json, error-handling, fetch-api

Run code and I get:

> "Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

How can I fix it?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const BASE_URL = "https://dummyjson.com/products";

export default function App() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setProduct(res);
      })
      // .then(console.log)
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {product.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.products.brand}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I tried change another API and it dose not have error

Answer (score -1):

The problem is what type of data in file json. In this case data' type is object so I can not use map to render product.

first I change useState hook from empty array to object

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({ products: [] });
```

then fetch data from api

```
  const fetchData = () => {
     fetch(`${BASE_URL}?limit=5`)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
        setProduct(data);
     });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();
  });
```

after fecth data and set to state I render it

Comment: This is not an answer. This is additional context about your question.When you need to add additional information to your question, use the edit button. The answer button should only be used for answering questions.